# Inverse function to format-date

Tags: date, xslt, format, xslt-2.0

in xslt 2.0, the function `format-date` will convert a date to string in a desired format, e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select  = "format-date(xs:date('2000-01-01'), '[D01] [MN,*-3] [Y0001]', 'en', (), ())"/>
```

results in

```
01 JAN 2000.
```

My question is: which function takes `01 JAN 2000` as input and outputs `2000-01-01`?

Comment: There is no such function in XSLT.  `01 JAN 2000` is a meaningless string. You can write your own function (assuming the format is known), though. Or perhaps borrow one from Java, if it has it.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid there was no such function because I could not find one...

Comment: Well, it's quite easy to DIY - see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868423/xslt-date-formating/22883013#22883013 or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775886/parsing-date-time-information-from-google-xml-feed-using-xsl-stylesheet/28776281#28776281

Comment: XPath 3.1 adds parse-ietf-date() which handles many of the date formats used in internet standards such as email (which are often very US-oriented). But there are too many varieties of date formats out there for a general solution to be viable.

Comment: Thanks. Since I will have to deal with several different formats a generic solution would have been handy, but there seems to be no way around creating several own functions. But if they introduce a function parse-ietf-date(), why don't they make it generic and support all formats that format-date() does? Would be incredibly handy.

Comment: It's much easier to define a syntax for converting one input format to a wide variety of output formats than to do the converse. A syntax that is sufficiently powerful to do the job properly would end up being very similar to doing it "by hand" using the replace() function and regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above:

> XPath 3.1 adds parse-ietf-date() which handles many of the date formats used in internet standards such as email (which are often very US-oriented). But there are too many varieties of date formats out there for a general solution to be viable.
>
> It's much easier to define a syntax for converting one input format to a wide variety of output formats than to do the converse. A syntax that is sufficiently powerful to do the job properly would end up being very similar to doing it "by hand" using the replace() function and regular expressions.
>
> It's quite easy to DIY.

**References**

- [XSLT Date Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868423/1113772)
- [Parsing Date/Time Information from Google XML feed using XSL Stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775886/1113772)